# Pandas: Adding data from a column to another dataframe until a specific time ends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

df1 is like below,

```
    A            time
0   32  2023-09-30 08:00:00
1   18  2023-09-30 08:01:00
2   61  2023-09-30 08:02:00
3   87  2023-09-30 08:03:00
4   46  2023-09-30 08:04:00
5   18  2023-09-30 08:05:00
6   65  2023-09-30 08:06:00
7   18  2023-09-30 08:07:00
8   10  2023-09-30 08:08:00
9   93  2023-09-30 08:09:00
```

and df2 is like below,

```
    AA  BB          Timestamp
0   27  54  2023-10-03 11:57:57.898397
1   28  56  2023-10-03 11:57:59.398397
2   29  58  2023-10-03 11:58:00.898397
3   30  60  2023-10-03 11:58:02.398397
4   31  62  2023-10-03 11:58:03.898397
5   32  64  2023-10-03 11:58:05.398397
6   33  66  2023-10-03 11:58:06.898397
7   34  68  2023-10-03 11:58:08.398397
8   35  70  2023-10-03 11:59:04.398397
```

I want to add the A data from df1 to df2 in a new column called CC.

I will provide a lower and upper bound for the df1 data to consider. Since df1 has 7 minutes of data and df2 has 2 minutes of data, I will specify a datetime range say 2023-09-30 08:02:00 to 2023-09-30 08:08:00.

I want to start adding the 'A' data from df1 to df2 starting from the lower bound, and continue adding 'A' data until df2 is filled. If 1 minute is completed in df2, I want to move on to the next entry in df1, this is how I want to fill CC.

The out put should look like this,

```
    AA  BB            Timestamp         CC
0   27  54  2023-10-03 11:57:57.898397  61
1   28  56  2023-10-03 11:57:59.398397  61
2   29  58  2023-10-03 11:58:00.898397  87
3   30  60  2023-10-03 11:58:02.398397  87
4   31  62  2023-10-03 11:58:12.898397  87
5   32  64  2023-10-03 11:58:24.398397  87
6   33  66  2023-10-03 11:58:40.898397  87
7   34  68  2023-10-03 11:58:52.398397  87
8   35  70  2023-10-03 11:59:04.398397  46
```

Here all examples I've given are synthetic examples, typically in my case df1 has 10500 rows of data in min frequency spanning one week and df2 has 472963 rows of data in millisecond frequency spanning 20hrs. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I would assume the second CC to be 87

Comment: Kindly add some pseudo code or some plain python code that explains the computation logic

Comment: @mozway sorry my bad, the second CC would should have 87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could define a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) delta from your reference (or first value of `df2`) and use this as a key for [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2023-09-30 08:02:00')

out = pd.merge_asof(df2.assign(delta=df2['Timestamp'].sub(df2['Timestamp'].iloc[0]).cumsum()),
                    df1.assign(delta=df1['time'].sub(start).where(lambda x: x>='0').cumsum())
                       .dropna(subset=['delta']).rename(columns={'A': 'CC'}),
                    on='delta', direction='forward'
                   ).drop(columns=['delta', 'time'])
```

Output:

```
   AA  BB                  Timestamp  CC
0  27  54 2023-10-03 11:57:57.898397  61
1  28  56 2023-10-03 11:57:59.398397  87
2  29  58 2023-10-03 11:58:00.898397  87
3  30  60 2023-10-03 11:58:02.398397  87
4  31  62 2023-10-03 11:58:03.898397  87
5  32  64 2023-10-03 11:58:05.398397  87
6  33  66 2023-10-03 11:58:06.898397  87
7  34  68 2023-10-03 11:58:08.398397  87
8  35  70 2023-10-03 11:59:04.398397  46
```

Intermediates:

```
   AA  BB                  Timestamp                 delta2   A                time          delta1
0  27  54 2023-10-03 11:57:57.898397        0 days 00:00:00  61 2023-09-30 08:02:00 0 days 00:00:00
1  28  56 2023-10-03 11:57:59.398397 0 days 00:00:01.500000  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
2  29  58 2023-10-03 11:58:00.898397 0 days 00:00:04.500000  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
3  30  60 2023-10-03 11:58:02.398397        0 days 00:00:09  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
4  31  62 2023-10-03 11:58:03.898397        0 days 00:00:15  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
5  32  64 2023-10-03 11:58:05.398397 0 days 00:00:22.500000  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
6  33  66 2023-10-03 11:58:06.898397 0 days 00:00:31.500000  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
7  34  68 2023-10-03 11:58:08.398397        0 days 00:00:42  87 2023-09-30 08:03:00 0 days 00:01:00
8  35  70 2023-10-03 11:59:04.398397 0 days 00:01:48.500000  46 2023-09-30 08:04:00 0 days 00:03:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really an elegant one.